# Spread TRANSPOSE function over non-adjacent columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

when I create an array in *Google Spreadsheets*, and use the `TRANSPOSE` function on the array, I get a new array, in which the first cell has the `TRANSPOSE` formula and the remaining cells have a `CONTINUE` function.

I want to put a new column between each column in the new array, but whenever I add a column, the cells of the array on the right of the new column shift to the left taking over that new column, such that there are no gaps between the new array cells.

I tried cutting and pasting the `CONTINUE` functions elsewhere, but the change is reversed every time.

**An ideas on how to split a `TRANSPOSE` function over non-adjacent columns?**

Note: The reason I want this is that I want to add data against each column into the new array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NOEXPAND function. For example:

`=NOEXPAND(TRANSPOSE(A1:A10))`

This will initially transpose the array into 10 contiguous cells. However, you should be able to then insert columns within that output, and shift the CONTINUE functions accordingly.

https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71291

Comment: it works exactly as you described. Legend!

On a side note, when I add more rows to the array, they don't automatically appear in the new array, but that's the cost of doing business. Thanks once again.